# Function template cannot deduce type if types T and U are the same

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

This question stems from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17870536/2018790) I received yesterday. For the following function, I am getting the error `couldn't deduce template parameter ‘V’` if both `T` and `U` are `std::complex<double>`. If `T` and `U` are different, the function compiles and works as intended.

```
template<class T, class U, class V>
auto operator*(const T a, const matrix<U> A) -> decltype(std::declval<T>()*std::declval<U>())
{
    matrix<V> B(A.size(1),A.size(2));
    for(int ii = 0; ii < B.size(1); ii++)
    {
        for(int jj = 0; jj < B.size(2); jj++)
        {
            B(ii,jj) = a*A(ii,jj);
        }
    }
    return B;
}
```

The usage is as follows:

```
std::complex<double> a1;
matrix<std::complex<double> > A1;
double a2;
matrix<std::complex<double> > A2;

/* ... */

matrix<std::complex<double> > B1 = a1*A1; // Compiler error
matrix<std::complex<double> > B2 = a2*A2; // Compiles and runs fine.
```

I should also mention I am compiling with g++ 4.7.3 and C++11 enabled.

**EDIT:**

A work around that I found is to also supply this function template:

```
template<class T>
matrix<T> operator*(const T a, const matrix<T> A)
{
    matrix<T> B(A.size(1),A.size(2));
    for(int ii = 0; ii < B.size(1); ii++)
    {
        for(int jj = 0; jj < B.size(2); jj++)
        {
            B(ii,jj) = a*A(ii,jj);
        }
    }
    return B;
}
```

With this addition, both cases above compile and run correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there must be a another overload of `operator*` involved, because `V` *cannot* be deduced given the declaration:

```
template<class T, class U, class V>
auto operator*(const T a, const matrix<U> A)
  -> decltype(std::declval<T>()*std::declval<U>());
```

The only way to call this function is to specify `V` explicitly, e.g., `operator*<int, long, long>(...)`.

---

Edit: Looking at the signature for `operator*(T, matrix<T>)` in the second code example, it would appear that your first code sample should read:

```
template<class T, class U>
auto operator*(const T a, const matrix<U>& A) -> matrix<decltype(a*A(0,0))>
{
    matrix<decltype(a*A(0,0))> B(A.size(1),A.size(2));
    for(int ii = 0; ii < B.size(1); ii++)
    {
        for(int jj = 0; jj < B.size(2); jj++)
        {
            B(ii,jj) = a*A(ii,jj);
        }
    }
    return B;
}
```

`operator*(T,matrix<T>)` should not be necessary as a special case.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it was first and also provided the solution I ended up using. All three answers were helpful and provided similar information, thank you.

Comment: `matrix<decltype(std::declval<T>()*std::declval<U>())>` can be simplified to `matrix<decltype(a*A(0,0))>`

Comment: @MooingDuck Yeah, when I saw `decltype(std::declval<T>()*std::declval<U>())` I reflexively moved it before the declaration without thinking. Simplifying in a trailing return type greatly improves readability though. I'll incorporate in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think if T and U are different another function is being called, because the compiler is right, V cannot be deduced, period. Even I can't deduce what you think that parameter should be.  [Here's proof that the second doesn't compile and run either](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=aecb4c6e792a2f0cab07107a7acf0962-0f11904895a20602a6e5ca9f4b5b0039), which means a different function is being called in that case.  The obvious solution is to simply remove the `class V` template parameter type, and simply use the deduced type.  Maybe you wanted something [more like this?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=2a6b963bd1b7f1f2a8ae5ae65abc899d-0f11904895a20602a6e5ca9f4b5b0039)

Looking at your code again, the one that you say fails is `complex * matrix`, while the second is `matrix*matrix`.  what other `operator*` are defined?

---

Unrelated, the three normal ways to accept parameters are `T`, `const T&`, or `T&&`.  There's very little reason to have a `const T` parameter type.  I believe you are missing a `&`?

Comment: My `matrix` class does have an `operator*(const matrix)` defined but I don't think the examples above are calling it. I will try to use your suggested code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not that `T` and `U` are the same, but that there is noting in the function prototype mentioning the `V` type.

Considering you use `V` to declar B that you return, and that you define the return type as T()*U(), I wonder what `matrix<V>` should be.

I would expect B and the return type to be `matrix<decltype(declval<T>()*declval<U>())>`, with no V (that should not be in the parameter list)